# Sitecore Form Number Field with plus and minus icon

Tags: sitecore-forms

I need Sitecore Form Number Field with plus and minus icon that will increment and decrement entered value.
How to get this kind of field. Any OOTB filed can be used with some minor updates.

Comment: You need to create custom field, take some idea from the link - https://coveoticore.wordpress.com/2019/11/21/sitecore-9-forms-how-to-create-a-unique-auto-incremental-id-field/

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by **Gaurav** you need to develop a custom field. Use the OOTB field `Number`, which is located at `Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates`, and create your field. This is a good starting point because the biggest changes will rely on the View as this field already has a `plus` and a `minus` feature but instead of `+` and `-` it uses arrow icons.

The Number field:

[image]